# VBA - Return the address/name of a user selected range

Tags: excel, vba, range

This might be too simple and I don´t know how to express it exactly.

I have an Input box to select a range from an external xslx file:

```
Set v1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select table", Type:=8)
```

What I am trying to do, is to make the VBA return as string the "selected range" to be input later in a formula, e.g.

```
'[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$K$24
```

this should go inside a formula, e.g.:

```
Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-4]," & v1 & ",5,0)"
```

Many thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
Range("E3").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-4]," & v1.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, external:=True) & ",5,0)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply: The above code returns run time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error.